# CodeIgniter with Kendoui grid

Tags: php, codeigniter, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Before Posting, i searched over web about related problems, but couldn't find any relevant help for my problem.

I am working on web application under CodeIgniter.
in which i am using KendoUI.
KendoUi is installed.

Problem is i want to use KendoUi grid, but that grid followes the json format and someothers like xml.

But issue is, the documentation i saw over the web on kendoUi website, according to them i will need to have another data source file. which should include the echo query of database which will be used as data source for the grid.

But i want to know is it possible in codeigniter if kendoui grid directly load the data from the database instead of echoing the data on ohter php file and then putting it on the grid.

If and only if it is not possible then what approach should i follow for codeigniter mvc pattern for implement the grid? should i make another dir in with the name of data in my directory? or what should i do..

Really need all of your guidance in it.

New to KendoUi and codeigniter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kendo UI operates on the client-side. Your data is server-side. The only way to get your data into the grid is to pass it via a server-side function.

In your case, using CodeIgniter, this is very simple. Your controller needs to serve up the page that contains the Grid and the required JavaScript. The `read` section of the datasource's `transport` should point to a URL that serves the data.

In your case, that URL will be to a CodeIgniter method. Let's say you want your grid to display employee information, the `read` URL would point to `employees\gridread` (or whatever).

The `employees\gridread` method would make a call to the `employees_model` to gram the employee records. It then returns the employee data in JSON format. The controller might look something like:

```
    public function gridread()
    {
        $limit = $this->input->post('take',TRUE);
        $offset = $this->input->post('skip',TRUE);
        $sort = $this->input->post('sort',TRUE);
        $filter = $this->input->post('filter',TRUE);

        $data = $this->employees_model->GridRead($limit, $offset,$sort,$filter);

        if ($data):
            header("Content-type: application/json");
            echo json_encode($data);
        else:
            // send server error
            header("HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error");
            echo "Failed to read data!";
        endif;
    }
```

You would need a function in your model that handles the `$limit, $offset, $sort, $filter` values to return the requested data.

EDIT: There's actually a much easier way to hook up CodeIgniter (or whatever PHP framework) to work with Kendo Grids and that is to use Kendo's `DataSourceResult.php` which you can find by viewing a Grid demo and switching the source to PHP.

It handles the Ajax request, including any filtering, sorting and paging, and returns the data in the format the Grid requires.

I've edited it slightly so that it can be loaded using CI's `$this->load->library` method and it gets the database settings from the config file.